# Acceptable to use domain in Username?

Tags: discussion

I've seen 3-4 other members do it, but is it acceptable to put your domain in your Username?

The purpose would be for slight promotional value, where other members may be curious about "what website does this member own?" and visit it, rather than having to click the Username to view the Profile and then to Website, which can be discouraging and/or not worth the effort.

There don't seem to be any rules against this specifically, since there aren't any services or products being advertised.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

General StackExchange questions are often fielded first at [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com):

> I'm not seeing the downside.
>
> If a user is posting good content, who cares what their user name is?
>   If you're implying some sort of spammy-ness to the name they choose,
>   I'm still not seeing the downside. They still have to post good
>   content to get their name in lights. That's a net win to us!
>
> The identity you choose is a personal thing. If someone wanted to be
>   called (for example) "Ubuntu Fanboi", we wouldn't be having this
>   conversation. So is a username like "AskUbuntu.com" really all that
>   different? It's not indiscriminate advertising... it's a username; and
>   it's not a part of the information content of this site. In short,
>   there is no "spam" to a username.

-
Robert Cartiano on meta.stackoverflow.com's [Are user names that represent domains allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100860/are-user-names-that-represent-domains-allowed)

If the domain used leads to questionable or obscene content it might be an issue, but otherwise it appears to be generally accepted.